Access service running on Debian 12 in a VirtualBox installed on a Windows machine
SCENARIO
I am trying to access a service (Service) running on a Linux Debian 12 virtual machine (Guest) running on Oracle VirtualBox installed on a Windows 11 pro machine (Host).
Using an Ipv6, I am able to reach the service S1 from a computer within my local network but I cannot reach the service from another network.
On VirtualBox I have installed Linux Debian 12 (Guest). On Linux I'm running a service on port 3000 (Service).
From within my local network I can reach the Service and also I can ssh into the Guest machine. But from another network I can't reach the Service and I cannot ssh into Guest.
I would like to reach my Service using an ipv6 network.
ENV / SETTINGS
1. Host Machine
Physical machine with Windows 11 pro installed. The host has Oracle VirtualBox installed.
2. VirtualBox
Adapter1: Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (Bridged Adapter, Realtek RTL8192EU Wireless LAN 802.11n USB 2.0 Network Adapter)
3. Router
Virgin Media Hub 6. ISP Virgin Ireland. Ipv6 Network (no Ipv4, no port forwarding)
4. VirtualMachine (Guest)
Linux Debian 12
If I run:
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all

I get:
public (active)
    target: default
    icmp-block-inversion: no
    interfaces: enp0s3
    sources:
    services: dhcpv6-client ssh
    ports: 3000/tcp 22/tcp
    protocols:
    forward: yes
    masquerade: no
    forward-ports:
    source-ports:
    icmp-blocks:
    rich rules:

ATTEMPTS
I have tried disabling windows firewall and router firewall.
When I disable windows firewall and router firewall and I ping the Host machine I get the following:
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 40.508/42.347/45.456/1.893 ms

And if I ping the Guest machine I get the following:
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 43.348/47.323/50.534/3.104 ms

It seems that the machine are reachable but I can't still access the Service (https://[ipv6]:3000 is unreachable, ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE) or ssh (ssh: connect to host ipv6 port 22: No route to host)

Is the IPv6 address a Link-local address? If so, that could explain why the IPv6 address is reachable from the local network, but not another network.

No it's not a Link-local address. It's a scope global temporary dynamic ipv6 addr (2a02:...)
